# Circular presentation of UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

Basically I'm wondering what the proper way to present and release view controllers is.

My original understanding was that ViewControllerA presents ViewControllerB with -presentViewController: Animated: Completion:. Then ViewControllerB can release himself by calling -dismissViewControllerAnimated: Completion:.

Now, if I have three view controllers, A, B and C. A presents B, B presents C, and C returns to to A, how should I write this? I tried to call a dismiss from C on B, but that doesn't work. The only thing that actually seems to work is having C present A again, but is this proper?

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: by general rule of thumb creator should be responsible for destruction as well.

Comment: "I tried to call a dismiss from C on B, but that doesn't work" It works if you do it correctly, so you need to think about why it "doesn't work" for _you_. Perhaps you should ask about _that_ (and show your attempted code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not proper to present A again. This will add a new  instance, and as you go forward again to B and C, those will also be new instances. From C, you can either use an unwind segue to go back to A, or you can call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion` on `self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController`. If the first view controller in a series of presenting view controller does a dismissal, it cause all the presented controllers to be deallocated (assuming you  aren't holding any other strong reference to them).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! After messing around with this implementation a while, I began to notice that global variables were left with their previous values. Once I present the view again, the global variables are not refreshed. Is there a reason why they are not cleared out with the release of the view itself?

Comment: @Jaun7707, that's the nature of globals, and a good reason not to use them.

Comment: What do global variables belong to then, if not the view itself?

Comment: @Jaun7707 They belong to the app itself I guess. I don't really know exactly how they're stored, but they exist for the life of the app. Is there a particular reason you're using a global variable?

Comment: I was just using global variables as an easy way for each method in the implementation of the ViewController, to access the data they hold. Should I be using '@property (nonatomic/atomic whatever)' in the '@interface' of the ViewController instead?

Comment: @Jaun7707 Yes, you should use properties. You can put them in the .h file if you want those properties to be visible to other classes. Otherwise, you should put them in the class extension at the top of the .m file.